# How can i use in ( select method in linq?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, linq-to-sql

how can i write "**in( select**" method in linq?

I'm trying to convert :

```
UPDATE ActualAmountsByLocation SET isCustomerItem=1 WHERE ItemBarcode IN (SELECT barcode FROM StockMaterials WHERE barcode=@Barcode AND ownership=1)
```

I've tried like this:

```
    Array stockMaterials = ( from s in stockMovementCtx.StockMaterials where s.barcode == Barcode && s.ownership ==1 select s).ToArray();
                           actualAmountsByLocation = (from a in stockMovementCtx.ActualAmountsByLocations
                                                       where a.ItemBarcode.Contains(stockMaterials)
                                                      select a).First();
```

Comment: That is pretty much how I would do it, too. But I would use .FirstOrDefault() plus null-check in the end instead of .First(). Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an IN query you need to reverse the sense of the contains.  Also, no need to materialize the first query, IMO.

```
var stockMaterials = from s in stockMovementCtx.StockMaterials
                     where s.barcode == Barcode && s.ownership ==1
                     select s;
actualAmountsByLocation = (from a in stockMovementCtx.ActualAmountsByLocations
                           where stockMaterials.Contains( a.ItemBarcode)
                           select a).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.
Remove the `.ToArray` call to prevent the query from being executed directly, and make your `stockMaterials` variable of type `IQueryable<StockMaterial>`.

Answer (score 0):

This what you're looking for?

```
ActualAmountsByLocation = StockMaterials.Where(s => s.barcode == Barcode && s.ownership == 1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var stockMaterials = (from s in stockMovementCtx.StockMaterials
                          where s.barcode == Barcode && s.ownership == 1
                          select s).ToArray();
    var actualAmountsByLocation = (from a in stockMovementCtx.ActualAmountsByLocations
                                   where stockMaterials.Contains(a.ItemBarcode)
                                   select a).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this code example below is helpful for you

```
// these are using linq methods
var barcodes = stockMovementCtx.StockMaterials
                 .Where(s => s.barcode == Barcode && s.ownership == 1)
                 .Select(s => s.barcode);
var amounts = stockMovementCtx.ActualAmountsByLocations
                .Where(a => barcodes.Contains(a.ItemBarCode))
                .FirstOrDefault();
// if you would like to use the query expressions instead, here they are
//var barcodes = from s in stockMovementCtx.StockMaterials
//               where s.barcode = Barcode && s.ownership == 1
//               select s.barcode;
//var amounts = (from a in stockMovementCtx.ActualAmountsByLocations
//              where barcodes.Contains(a.ItemBarCode.Contains)
//              select a).FirstOrDefault();

// helpful to use FirstOrDefault if you are not sure that the query will return a result
if (amounts != null) {
  // change value
  amounts.IsCustomerItem = 1;
  // update database
  stockMovementCtx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making update on LinQ is so easy thing, check the code block below for example.

```
var user = (from s in dataContext.USERS
```

Calling Users Table, and setting where condition.

`where s.UserId.Equals(id)
select s).FirstOrDefault();`

I want to make change on user email.(Dont forget this: If you call with ToList(), you need to control list count to avoid exception for ex: if(user.Count > 0)..)

Updating user:

```
s.EmailAddress = serkan@serkanhekimoglu.com;
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

and your data will be updated after SubmitChanges();